# Find out number of times a sql_id was executed

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to know if in oracle, I can somehow see how many times a query (sql_id) was executed in the past lets say 24 hours ?

I basically have a db-user which is executing an sql_id with different bind variables. what I want to see is how many times this specific sql_id was executed regardless of which bind value was used.

Thanks
Saad

Comment: look in v$sqlarea

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
select count(*) as HowManyTimes
from v$sql
where last_load_time > sysdate-1
  and sql_id = @your_sql_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It may give some insight into checking the count of recently executed queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS execution_count
FROM v$sql
WHERE sql_id = '7xuhvctk9aptv'
  AND last_active_time > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR; --or MINUTE
```