# How to get a count of the number of times a sql statement has executed in X hours?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle db. I want to be able to count the number of times that a SQL statement was executed in X hours. For instance, how many times has the statement `Select * From ExampleTable` been executed in the past 5 hours?

I tried looking in V$SQL, V$SQLSTATS, V$SQLAREA, but they only keep a record of a statement's total amount of executions. They don't store what times the individual executions occurred. Is there any view I missed, or something else that does keep track of each individual statement execution + timestamp so that I can query by which have occurred X hours ago? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this if it helps for similar questions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434499/6332029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views in the Active Workload Repository store historical SQL execution information, specifically the view [`DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4051.htm).

The view is not perfect; it contains a summary of the *top* SQL statements.  This is almost perfect information for performance tuning - in practice, sampling will catch any performance problem.  But if you're looking for a perfect record of every SQL execution, as far as I know the only way to get that information is through [tracing](https://blog.dbi-services.com/enable-10046-tracing-for-a-specific-sql/), which is buggy and slow.

Hopefully this query is good enough:

```
select begin_interval_time, end_interval_time, executions_delta, dba_hist_sqlstat.*
from dba_hist_sqlstat
join dba_hist_snapshot
    on dba_hist_sqlstat.snap_id = dba_hist_snapshot.snap_id
    and dba_hist_sqlstat.instance_number = dba_hist_snapshot.instance_number
order by begin_interval_time desc, sql_id;
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that AWR is not free. Although we can query AWR tables as shown we are only **licensed** to do so if our organisation has bought the Oracle Database Diagnostic Pack, an chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for putting this in an answer instead of a comment (I don't have the required reputation), but I think you may be out of luck.  Here is an AskTOM asking basically the same question: [AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4359442000346233840).  Tom says unless you are using ASH that just isn't something the database is designed to do.